# What "ladder sub {...}" means in perl?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm reading [tweetylicious source from github](https://github.com/garu/tweetylicious) to study Mojolicious framework:

However I'm confused by below piece of code `ladder sub ...`. What does it mean in Perl? It looks like not a regular Perl grammar.

Btw, I'm with Strawberry Perl 5.

```
# The rest of the routes are specific to logged in users, so we
# add a ladder to make sure (instead of making sure inside each route)
ladder sub {
    my $self = shift;
    return 1 if $self->session('name');
    $self->redirect_to('/login') and return;
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a call to a subroutine called `ladder` that expects a code reference as its first argument. It is equivalent to

```
$tmpfunc = sub {
    my $self = shift;
    return 1 if $self->session('name');
    $self->redirect_to('/login') and return;
};
ladder($tmpfunc);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But how I fix the compilation error? I tried change  it to the example style, but then I blocked by cgi.pm:has description => 'Start application with CGI';
has usage => sub { shift->extract_usage };

Comment: @Hao the code you're looking at is from 2011. The Mojolicious project is quite active and the API changes frequently. I've searched through the github repo and I can only find two references to `ladder`, when it was added in 2010. It has since been removed, but the changelog doesn't reveal when. I think you should look for more modern examples.

Comment: @simbabque Got. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Hao I went on IRC and asked in #mojolicious. The creator of the project says it probably went out in 2010 before version 1.0. So I would say it's safe to assume we shouldn't be using it today. The modern equivalent is called `under`, btw.

Comment: @Hao thank you. We're all just people here. I hope you're having fun learning Perl although you're experiencing a bit of a setback right now! :)